# How Can I Take Oracle 10G Data Into a PHP Array and Then Convert It to a JavaScript Array?

Tags: php, javascript, oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to define a PHP array, then connect to Oracle 10g and take the data requested from the connection and put it into the PHP array.

Finally, I want to take the PHP array and convert it into a JavaScript array.

Here's what I'm trying.

Can somebody point out why this is not working and perhaps offer a solution?

Thank you.

```
        $dbArray = array();
        $conn = oci_connect("username", "password", "connecturl");
        $query = 'select endpoint_name from endpoint_ref order by endpoint_name asc';
        $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
        $result = oci_execute($stid); 
        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)) 
        {
            foreach ($row as $item) {
                array_push($dbArray, $item);
                var_dump($dbArray);
                echo $dbArray;
            }
        }
        $jsArray = json_encode($dbArray);
```

Also, how can I set this JavaScript variable named "availableTags" to equal my newly encoded JavaScript array?

```
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = jsArray;
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: That seems fine, what's not working exactly?

Comment: I'm not getting anything back from var_dump and I can't seem to use the new 'jsArray' in my JavaScript function.

Comment: Not sure why is not dumping anything but to use the variable in JS you need to grab it with an AJAX request, it won't be automagically assigned...

Comment: Oh, actually, if you move the var_dump outside of the loop, it will show the data. It working. Now I just have to figure out this AJAX request business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion in my question was correct, the problem was the JavaScript function. This is how to properly call the JSON encoded PHP array containing the Oracle 10g data.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($dbArray); ?>;
        $( "#endPointName" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Was just about to post the same answer, did a bunch of studying up on OCI8 before I noticed the comment that said that was working after all. Oh well, learned something new :)

Comment: Well thanks for trying to help, my friend. It looks like I need to study up my JavaScript, as that was the problem.